# paypal ipn case is not calling in paypal "pay now"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

paypal ipn case is not calling in paypal "pay now".
In paypal button the following is set.

```
return : "http://localhost/paypal.php?ch=return"

cancel_return : "cancel_return" value="http://localhost/paypal.php?ch=cancel"

notify_url : value="http://localhost/paypal.php?ch=ipn"
```

paypal_form.php

```
<form name="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="no_notes" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_1309158746_biz@gmail.com">

<input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value="http://localhost/paypal.php?ch=return">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" id="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/paypal.php?ch=cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" id="notify_url" value="http://localhost/paypal.php?ch=ipn">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_GB/i/btn/btn_paynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110429-1/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

paypal.php

```
<?

include('db_connect.php');

$choice=isset($_GET['ch'])?$_GET['ch']:'';


switch($choice){

case 'return':
        print "Thank You For Buying this product,Please Visit Again,If is there any complements Then suggest us..";
    break;
case 'ipn':
    $sql="INSERT INTO paypal(add_date) VALUES(now())";
    mysql_query($sql);

    $x = fopen('test1.txt','w+');
    $str2 = 'post data:dfydfhgfhjg'; 
    foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
        $str2 .= $k.'--'.$v;
    }
    fwrite($x,$str2);
    fclose($x);

    break;
case 'cancel':
        print "Thank You for visiting this site,Please inform your friend to buy products through paypal which is easy service... ";
    break;
}   
?>
```

Comment: hello, can you describe what u have written in paypal_form.php..? what parameters are suppose to be post on PAYNOW button..? Thx.

Comment: Ipsita Rout, you've asked 6 questions but have not awarded anyone for a correct answer. Can you please ensure you probably reward those who invest time in providing you with the correct answer? This is not just for this questions, but all others you've filed over the past weeks as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An IPN script can't reside on localhost, since PayPal will open its own connection to it from their side. Use a FQDN instead.

Comment: Thanks Robert.Actually I was trying to run my code in local xampp server.But when I ran it in external server.It gave the required output.Thanks a lot